PydanticSchemaGenerationError error as I try to import arize-phoenix
I wanted to try using arize-phoenix to trace my llm calls.
I was trying to follow this tutorial notebook from my local environment. After pip installing the package, I get an error at the very first line "import phoenix as px." The error message says:
#Phoenix Setup
import phoenix as px # type: ignore
phoenix_session = px.launch_app()

PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for typing_extensions.NoDefault. Set `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in the model_config to ignore this error or implement `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on your type to fully support it.

If you got this error by calling handler(<some type>) within `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` then you likely need to call `handler.generate_schema(<some type>)` since we do not call `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on `<some type>` otherwise to avoid infinite recursion.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/u/schema-for-unknown-type

I thought all I needed to do was to run pip install arize-phoenix, but I guess not?
I am wondering if this is some dependency conflict or compatibility issue.
Could someone explain why this error is happening and how to fix it?
